# JQuery append to div

Tags: jquery, append

```
<body>
<div id="scrollup">
<div class="link">
<br><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google1</a>
<br><a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a>
</div>
<div class="link">
<br><a href="http://www.Microsoft.com/">Microsoft</a>
<br><a href="http://www.Apple.com/">Apple</a>
</div>
<div class="link">
<br><a href="http://www.cisco.com/">Cisco</a>
<br><a href="http://www.Dell.com/">Dell</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I want to use JQuery Append to add list of Hrefs into classes, i have list of hyperlinks stored in array and i want to append them in groups, code shows how do i want the hrefs to be defined

And please note that i do not know how many hyperlinks are there in the array and also the number of (class="link") depend on the number of hyperlinks by adding (e.g. 4 hrefs into each class)

Comment: you have not posted the code

Comment: Show the code and it´s easier to help you out m8

Comment: yes he has.. he just didn't format it. [edited] also.. what have you tried?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience guys but this is my first time to post question here and was not aware of how to post the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Demo</title>
            <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

            <script>
                var links = ['http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601373/jquery-append-to-div',
                        'http://jsfiddle.net/VCjLX/',
                        'https://www.google.at/'];


                $(function () {
                    //get all containers where we append the links
                    var containers = $('.link');
                    //iterate over all links
                    $(links).each(function () {
                        var link = $('<a>', {
                            href: this,
                            text: this
                        });
                        //append the link to the containers (it gets appened to all elements!)
                        containers.append(link);
                        //append the line break (again to all elements)
                        containers.append('<br />');
                    });
                });

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="link"></div>
            <br />
            <div class="link"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R2kTC/

Comment: thank you for your quick response, i think my intial code cause some confution, i have modified the URLs in the code.

Comment: And also as i have mentioned, i do not know how many classes i have to define initially.